# SWT-File-Save-dialog: how to show overwrite-confirmation

Tags: java, swt, savefiledialog, confirmation

Is it possible to show a overwrite-confirmation **while** the SWT file-save-dialog is shown and the user selected an existing file? Of course, I can show the file-save-dialog and later show a confirmation dialog, but this would be bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FileDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/FileDialog.html#setOverwrite%28boolean%29) has setOverwrite method, you could use that.